# Regex captures more than wanted

Tags: regex, tags, wikipedia

I want to remove references on Wikipedia with AutoWikiBrowser ([.net](/questions/tagged/.net) regex flavor), an automatic editor that handles  regexes, but I am facing a newbie problem with the  tags.

For example, I want to remove all references containing `example.com`, e.g.

```
<ref>{{cite web|title=Bar|url=https://example.com/bar}}</ref>
```

I tried the basic regex `<ref>.*?example.com.*?</ref>` (replaced with nothing), but it also captures everything after the first `<ref>` tag encountered, e.g:

```
<ref>{{cite web|title=Foo|url=https://zzz.com/foo}}</ref> blah-blah <ref>{{cite web|title=Bar|url=https://example.com/bar}}</ref>
```

I tried lookarounds with the tags, but the issue is it is not capturing the tags.

I am sorry to ask such a simple question, but I have been searching for the last hour to no avail, I speak English quite fluently, but not when it comes to technical terms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will match a `<ref>` tag that includes `example.com` before the closing `</ref>`:

```
<ref>(?:(?!<\/ref>).)*example\.com.*?<\/ref>
```

This matches:

- `<ref>` : the characters `<ref>`
- `(?:(?!<\/ref>).)*` : any number of characters that do not start a closing `</ref>` tag (using a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed))
- `example\.com` : the characters `example.com`
- `.*?` : a minimal number of characters
- `<\/ref>` : the characters `</ref>`

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wgL7yO/1)

Note dependent on your regex engine and its regex delimiters you may not need the `\` before the `/` in `</ref>`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I should really learn about these lookarounds, I still do not understand clearly how this "positive lookahead/non-capturing group/negative lookahead" really works....

Comment: @oli_vi_er the linked article (and that whole site) is very useful, as is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)

Comment: I have one more question : how would you you if there are mulitples lines inside the <ref></ref> tags ? singleline doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: @oli_vi_er it should work with the `s` flag: https://regex101.com/r/npHdSW/1. What language are you using?

Comment: AutoWikiBrowser (.net regex flavor), as edited by Gilles Quénot ?
I already tried with the "singleline" box ticked, and it captures from the preceding <ref> tag

Comment: /s actually works, I made a mistake because AutoWikiBrowser has a strange way to highlight the text it will remove.

Comment: @oli_vi_er good to hear. Another possibility would be to use `[\S\s]` in place of `.` see https://regex101.com/r/qXOKET/1